# Add double value to SQL float in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have got a SQL table with a property 'Stock' and datatype float.
According to several posts the equivalent type in C# is double.

So I have got a input which is a string and I convert it to a double value like this:

```
var number = Convert.ToDouble(numberAsString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat);
```

I have the follwing code to add the number on top of the stock:

```
result.Bestand += number;
```

Somehow (this is really strange to me) if I add "0,1" exactly three times, the value changes to  `15,299999999999999`. I don't know why though.

Remember: I am using commas instead of decimal points.

Comment: That is how floating point values work.  They are approximate.  That is why SQL supports fixed point formats (`numeric`/`decimal`).

Comment: So I should use numeric or decimal instead of float?

Comment: I will say yes...go for decimal for the reason @GordonLinoff commented

Comment: Okay thanks and double in C# still?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ich muss meinen Datentyp aus einem Eingabefeld auslesen und dann in eine Kommazahl konvertieren

Comment: @Anokrize: Use `decimal` if you expect that `0.1`+`0.1`+`0.1` is `0.3`

Comment: Great it worked! Put it as the answer and I will accept it. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

You should use numeric/decimal type in SQL. But why there is a need to read a value as string if you have the stock is of type float?